# I have 2011model John Deere D110, 186 hours

Tags: camshaft, lawnmower

Deere service dept. says needs camshaft repair, price $900.
Mower has been serviced by Deere yearly. 
I'm wondering if anyone has experienced a problem like this one, and what did they figure out.Seems like expensive repair with mower with 186 hours.

Comment: $900 seems expensive for that problem considering you can purchase a totally new engine for $700.  https://engine4less.com/31P677-0144.html

It does, however, seem to be an odd problem to have with only 186 hours and regular service by that dealer.  Perhaps you should have a discussion with the service manager.

Comment: Thank you jwh20 for commenting on my problem. Service manager agreed, saying mower old enough to need this kind of repair. He wasnt really concerned about hours. Think I will contact Briggs & Stratton for their input. Thanks again. I really appreciate it.